# spark scala reading text file with line delimiter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have a one text file with following format.

```
id##name##subjects$$$
1##a##science
english$$$
2##b##social
mathematics$$$
```

I want to create a `DataFrame` like

```
id | name | subject
1  | a    | science
   |      | english
```

When I do this Scala I get `RDD[String]` only. How can I convert `RDD[String]` to a `DataFrame`

```
val rdd = sc.textFile(fileLocation)
val a = rdd.reduce((a, b) => a + " " + b).split("\\$\\$\\$").map(f => f.replaceAll("##","")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the text file you provide and assuming you want the all of your example file converted to the following (put example text into a file example.txt)

```
+---+----+-----------+
| id|name|   subjects|
+---+----+-----------+
|  1|   a|    science|
|   |    |    english|
|  2|   b|     social|
|   |    |mathematics|
+---+----+-----------+
```

you can run the code below (spark 2.3.2)

```
val fileLocation="example.txt"
val rdd = sc.textFile(fileLocation)

def format(x : (String, String, String)) : String = {
  val a = if ("".equals(x._1)) "| " else x._1 + " | "
  val b = if ("".equals(x._2)) "| " else x._2 + " | "
  val c = if ("".equals(x._3)) "" else x._3
  return a + b + c
}

var rdd2 = rdd.filter(x => x.length != 0).map(s => s.split("##")).map(a =>  {
  a match {
  case Array(x) =>
    ("", "", x.split("\\$\\$\\$")(0))
  case Array(x, y, z) =>
   (x, y, z.split("\\$\\$\\$")(0))
  }
})

rdd2.foreach(x => println(format(x)))

val header = rdd2.first()

val df = rdd2.filter(row => row != header).toDF(header._1, header._2, header._3)
df.show

val ds = rdd2.filter(row => row != header).toDS.withColumnRenamed("_1", header._1).withColumnRenamed("_2", header._2).withColumnRenamed("_3", header._3)
ds.show
```

Comment: would you please explain this block   `a match {`
  `case Array(x) =>`
`    ("", "", x.split("\\$\\$\\$")(0))`
  `case Array(x, y, z) =>`
   `(x, y, z.split("\\$\\$\\$")(0))`
  `}`

Comment: Each row in input file is mapped to an array of strings. So there are 2 cases. A single column in the input or 3 columns. For a single column we return "" for the first 2 columns, for 3 columns we return all 3 columns as tuples. We strip off the "$$$" off the end of the last column regardless using your split technique.

Comment: I have a more columns like this but I have only one column with multi line . How can make this for  all columns ...

Comment: I do not understand. You would have to provide an example input. I have answered the question as you specified it.